# Objects are not valid as a React child in react-stacked-center-carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, slider

I am using react-stacked-center-carousel and the code is defined in

[The sandbox i am using as refrence](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-snowflake-k3rf75?file=/src/App.js)

[The sandbox i am truing to do it my self](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-dirac-ptfl8z?file=/src/App.js)
now when i pass an array of objects

```
const data = [
  {
    image: "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random=1",
    text: "hello"
  },
  {
    image: "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random=12",
    text: "lel"
  },
];
```

to

```
<StackedCarousel
                ref={carouselRef}
                slideComponent={Slide}
                slideWidth={450}
                carouselWidth={width}
                data={data}
                maxVisibleSlide={5}
                disableSwipe
                customScales={[1, 0.85, 0.7, 0.55]}
                transitionTime={450}
              />
```

this gives an error

Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

As i am defining data as an array

I am started for this so kindly help me out

The Slide.js file is as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import {
 StackedCarouselSlideProps
} from "react-stacked-center-carousel";
import "./Slide.css";

export const Slide = React.memo(function(StackedCarouselSlideProps) {
 const {
   data,
   dataIndex,
   isCenterSlide,
   swipeTo,
   slideIndex
 } = StackedCarouselSlideProps;

 const coverImage = data[dataIndex].image;
 const text = data[dataIndex].text;

 console.log(coverImage);
 return ( <
   div className = "card-card"
   draggable = {
     false
   } >
   <
   div className = {
     `cover fill ${isCenterSlide ? "off" : "on"}`
   } >
   <
   div className = "card-overlay fill"
   onClick = {
     () => {
       if (!isCenterSlide) swipeTo(slideIndex);
     }
   }
   /> <
   /div> <
   div className = "detail fill" >
   <
   div className = "discription" >
   <
   img style = {
     {
       width: 100
     }
   }
   alt = "j"
   className = "cover-image"
   src = {
     coverImage
   }
   /> <
   p > {
     text
   } < /p> <
   /div> <
   /div> <
   /div>
 );
});
```

Comment: Can you update your question with `Slide` component that you have used?

Comment: Specifically, remember to put [all the details in your post](/help/how-to-ask). External links are fine by only _in addition_ to having all the relevant (but [MCVE] form) code in your post. Your post needs to be answerable on its own, and future visitors need to be able to see whether your problem is their problem, too, without needing to visit external links.

Comment: @DulajAriyaratne I have updated the question including Slide.js
And thank you for the suggestion to a newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I exported slide component using named export, but imported it as a default import.

Changed my slide component import from

```
import Slide from "../components/Slide";
```

to

```
import {Slide} from "../components/Slide";
```

and it works as expected. The carousel itself has no issue.